# Solving differential equation $xdy + ydx = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve following equation

$$xdy + ydx = 0$$

My process: group variables

$$xdy = -ydx \ \ \ ; \ \ \ \frac{x}{dx} = -\frac{y}{dy}$$

Integrate

$$\int{\frac{dx}{x}} = \int{\frac{-dy}{y}}$$
$$\ln |x| + K = - \ln |y| + K$$

Solution 
$$\ln|xy| = K$$

However my textbook gives answer:

$$xy = K$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: $ln|xy| = K \Rightarrow xy = e^K$ and they call $K_1 = e^K$ so that $xy = K_1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach is alright. Note that if $\ln A = k$, then $A = e^k$ and if $k$ is a constant, then so is $e^k$ and you could rename it to (for example) $K$.

Other approach (using the product rule):
$$xdy+ydx = 0 \Leftrightarrow d(xy) = 0 \implies xy = C$$

Comment: wait can you elaborate on the product rule? interested in building intuition for patterns

Comment: Recall the rule $d(uv) = udv+vdu$, here just with $x$ and $y$. You see?

Comment: yes yes quite obvious in hindsight. thx

Comment: No problem & you're welcome!

Comment: If you remember the product rule from calculus 1 you can reverse it to help solve differential equations.  d/dx(f(x) * g(x)) = f(x)g'(x) + f'(x)g(x).  So if you have a differential equation of the form f(x)g'(x) + f'(x)g(x) = 0 you can recognize that to be the derivative of f(x)g(x) which can speed things up.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't going wrong.  Your solution and the textbook's solution are the same.  $e^K$ is just some arbitrary constant where $K > 0$.

As a side note you should be more careful in naming your constants.  You have $K$ on as the integration constant on both sides.  The should be named something like $K_1$ and $K_2$ because they can (and probably are) different.

Answer (score -1):

$$
Xdy + ydx =0
xdy = -- ydx
1/y dy = -- 1/x dx
$$

Integrating both sides;
$$
log |y| = -- log |x| + log |C| $$$$
log |y|  + log |x| = log |C| $$$$
log |xy| = log |C|
$$
Comparing respective parts;
$$xy = C$$$$
y = C/x 
$$, 
which is required general solution..